# "Send someone to do someting" vs. "send someone in to do something"

Tags: prepositions, difference

What is the difference in meaning beween *send someone to do something* and *send someone in to do something*? For example:

> The government decided to **send** troops to restore order in the region.
>
> The government decided to **send in** troops to restore order in the region.

Answer (score 1):

> The government decided to **send** troops to restore order in the region.

What I infer from the sentence is that, the Government has taken a decision of sending troops in the particular region for restoring peace and order. The decision is taken sitting in the high halls of the ministry. The action though may be taken immediately or at a future point of time.

> The government decided to **send in** troops to restore order in the region.

This sentence means that the operation is under way and the troops are right at the location of the attack or assault. More likely the action would be effective immediate rather than procrastinating the same.

Answer (score 0):

The government sent in troops to the region to restore order. That is proper phrasing.

They didn't send them to the region.

They probably sent munitions and supplies to the region.

**If people enter a place, they are sent in** or into the place.

The cops sent in sharpshooters to deal with the gunman.

in = more specific and means: into a place, region, area, etc.

If troops are sent to a region, it could be on the border. If they are **sent in**, they have crossed a line or separation.